# Possible in swift to do a recursive function call with javascriptcore?

Tags: swift, recursion, swift2, javascriptcore

I have a function that is called by javascript with JavascriptCore.
Now inside that function I have to evaluate a javascript again under a certain condition. This should call the same function.

```
let My_JS_Function: @convention(block) ( String, String, String ) -> ( ) = {
    thing_1, thing_2, thing_3
    in
    let my_Condition = true
    if my_Condition {        
      let c = JSContext()
      // compiling error: "Variable used within its own initial value"
      Context.setObject(unsafeBitCast(My_JS_Function, AnyObject.self), forKeyedSubscript: "My_JS_Function")
      c.evaluateScript("My_JS_Function("value 1","value 2","value 3");")
    }
  }
```

Now XCode tells me:

> Variable used within its own initial value

Does anybody know wheather there's a way how to solve this problem?
Maybe a way to write the *My_JS_Function* as a function and not like here as a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix the problem with avoiding having functions as properties.
Therefor I put the functionality in an extra class and used JSExport.

One example for how it can be done with JSExport can be [found here](http://nshipster.com/javascriptcore/).